# Magento custom report - access generated data

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom report in Magento fine, but need to add a summery of the data at the bottom. How do I access the generated data to create a summery? Thanks.
More information...

```
$gridBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('adminhtml_report.grid');
$collection = $gridBlock->getCollection();
$item = $collection->getItems();
```

But the items are empty, foreach on $collection returns empty as well. The data are shown in the grid area.

Comment: Is this question programming related?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes. So in PHP how do we access data set. Does it make sense?

Comment: Then you should tag this question appropriately and provide the current code you have written.